# Changing the size of the menu from the "Buffers" item in the menu bar in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Currently, the menu brought up by the `Buffers` menu item in the menu bar only shows the last 9 buffers and no more than about 29 characters of the buffer name. How can I change the number of buffers displayed in this menu and how can I get it to show more characters in the buffer name?

Comment: For a mouse-free approach, you should try using `M-x ibuffer` too (and then use `C-h m` to read about its filtering and grouping capabilities). I always recommend re-binding `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer`. These days I bind the 'menu' key on my keyboard to this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How 'bout `buffers-menu-buffer-name-length` and `buffers-menu-max-size`?
You may also prefer using C-mouse-1, which gives you a different kind of "buffers menu", which I personally prefer (so I just get rid of the "Buffers" menu with `(define-key global-map [menu-bar buffer] nil)`, thus saving scarce menubar real-estate).

Comment: Cross-linking to http://stackoverflow.com/q/10710467/324105, which is an analogous question for the different buffers menu Stefan mentions.