# How do I set the number of items in the mouse buffer menu in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

When I press ctrl+left-mouse-button in Emacs, I get the mouse buffer menu.  This is my favourite way of switching buffers, but the list of buffers doesn't have to be too long before it re-organises the list into sub menus (fundamental, LISP, others etc...).  I really hate this because I find it much harder to find the buffer I'm looking for.

My question is: How can I set the number of items in the mouse buffer menu that emacs will show before it breaks the menu into submenus?  (I want to increase it, obviously!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following two variables give you some control over this:

- `mouse-buffer-menu-maxlen`
- `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult`

My interpretation is that the latter is the maximum number of buffers in a given major mode before that mode gets its own sub-menu, and the former is the maximum number of buffers allowed in any sub/menu before it is split into multiple menus.

`setq` as appropriate, or
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `mouse` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!  It was the latter value that did it - I increased the number and got the effect I was looking for.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

full code with details to add to .emacs file is below

also note that `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult` takes precedence

to evaluate the below and see effect immediately, highlight and type `M-x eval-region` or put cursor inside each () and type `M-C-x`

```
;; "ctrl - left click" buffer menu: increase number of items shown
;; set max length of this list. default 20. see next.
(setq mouse-buffer-menu-maxlen 30)
;; set # buffer in a mode before grouping begins. takes precedence over previous
;; set to 1 to always group by mode. default 4
(setq mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult 8)
```