# Elisp: Buffer Menu

Tags: emacs, menu, elisp

Every time I hit CTRL + Left click in Emacs I get a list of all opened buffers.
How can I change the default output in order to pop up a menu customized by myself, I have something like this in mind:

```
Buffer Menu  
-----------
dot.C     >  ex1.c  
dot.java     ex2.c
dot.lisp     ex3.c
dot.?  
... 
-----------
```

For instance, every .c file would be stored inside dot.c entry as showed above.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you'd have one menu for `.c` files, and another for `.h` files, even though they're both using the same major mode? The standard menu categorizes based on major mode, so I think you'd need custom menu code to achieve that.

A hacky approach which springs to mind would be to define minimal derived major modes in order to associate each with a different filename extension, and then you *could* use the existing menus to achieve your goal.

If you didn't mean that, and grouping by major mode is fine, then the current system should already provide a solution.

In either case, the following may prove useful:

- [How do I set the number of items in the mouse buffer menu in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710467/how-do-i-set-the-number-of-items-in-the-mouse-buffer-menu-in-emacs)
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `mouse-buffer-menu` <kbd>RET</kbd>