# Sorting mouse-buffer-menu

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use mouse-buffer-menu a lot (when clicking left mouse with control a buffer menu pops up).
Is there a way to sort the list to keep maybe c and assembly files t the top.
Also, is there to keep all these priority files from being categorized into sub-directories in the list no matter how long the list of opened files is?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get what you are asking for ("a long list of C files and assembly files at the top then subfolders for all other files") without hacking the emacs sources.

However, you can arrange all buffers by modes: customize `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult` to 0, either using <kbd>M-x customize</kbd> or by adding

```
(custom-set-variables '(mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult 0))
```

to your `~/.emacs.el`.

See also:

1. [How do I set the number of items in the mouse buffer menu in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710467/how-do-i-set-the-number-of-items-in-the-mouse-buffer-menu-in-emacs)
2. [How to get Emacs buffer-menu always to show mode-names?](https://superuser.com/questions/565822/how-to-get-emacs-buffer-menu-always-to-show-mode-names)

Comment: Thanks sds.
As I mentioned I don't want "All" the files to be categorized into folders, only the non-important ones.
Basically, I want a long list of C files and assembly files at the top then subfolders for all other files.

Comment: @Ammari: I don't think you can get that without hacking emacs sources.